# Am I using the correct format specifier?

Tags: c

I wrote a simple calculator program tho the result is always coming out as -0.00000000
Here is a part of the code:

```
int main() {

  char symbol;
  double num1, num2;
  double total_multi = num1*num2;

  scanf("%lf %c %lf", &num1, &symbol, &num2);

  switch(symbol){
      case '*': printf("The answer is: %lf * %lf = %lf", num1, 
num2, total_multi );
      break;  }
    return 0;
}
```

Am I using the wrong format specifier or is it something else?

Comment: You're performing the multiplication before you read in the values.

Comment: Can you provide some example values that you have tried running with?

Comment: If you don't have loops, code is executed from top to bottom. Now with that information please do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) of your code and see it it makes sense.

Comment: Not your immediate problem, but you need to `#include <stdio.h>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format specifiers are correct, but you are multiplying `num1` with `num2` before initializing either with the call to `scanf`. If you move the initialization of `total_multi` after your call to `scanf`, you do not have this problem.

Also, when using `scanf` to read user input it is strongly recommended that you check that its return value matches the number of format specifiers in the format string:

```
double num1, num2;
double total_multi;

if(scanf("%lf %c %lf", &num1, &symbol, &num2) != 3)
{ 
     /* Handle scanf failure */ 
}
total_multi = num1 * num2;
```

On a less urgent note, `%lf` in a `printf` (rather than `scanf`) format string is redundant because `%f` applies to the type `double` and `float` values are automatically promoted to `double`.

Answer (score 1):

The mulply must be calculated with values. I moved "total_multi = num1*num2;" into loop.

```
  char symbol;
  double num1, num2;
  double total_multi;

  scanf("%lf %c %lf", &num1, &symbol, &num2);

  switch(symbol){
      case '*': 
          total_multi = num1*num2;
          printf("The answer is: %lf * %lf = %lf", num1, num2, total_multi );
      break;  }
    return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the correct format, if you pretend to work with `long` and `float` values.

But you must move your code to multiply numbers inside the case for `*`. In that moment, you already have the values read.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char symbol;
    double num1, num2, total_multi;

    scanf("%lf %c %lf", &num1, &symbol, &num2);


    switch(symbol){
        case '*':
            total_multi = num1*num2;
            printf("The answer is: %lf * %lf = %lf", num1, num2, total_multi);
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```